spring boot retry how to preserve first exception
A retry may lead to a new exception based on the first transaction. To aid in troubleshooting, how to preserve the first error message even if the maximum number  of retries is attempted.
Thanks

ChatGPT gave me the solution!
RetryConfig.java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryCallback;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryContext;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryListener;
import org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy;
import org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy;
import org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate;

import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
public class RetryConfig {

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(
                5,
                Collections.singletonMap(RuntimeException.class, true)
        );
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        // Configure the backoff policy
        ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(1000);
        backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2.0);
        backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

        retryTemplate.registerListener(new RetryListener() {
            @Override
            public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
                context.setAttribute("firstException", null);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
                Throwable firstException = (Throwable) context.getAttribute("firstException");
                if (context.getRetryCount() > 0 && firstException != null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Retry attempts exhausted. First error was: " + firstException.getMessage(), firstException);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
                if (context.getAttribute("firstException") == null) {
                    context.setAttribute("firstException", throwable);
                }
            }
        });

        return retryTemplate;
    }
}

RetryDao.java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RetryDao {
    private final RetryDao retryDao;

    public void testRetry() throws RuntimeException {
        log.info("GG retry");
        retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
            retryDao.testRetry(); // will throws Exception
        });
    }
}

